# Code execution is not going down

Tags: c#, .net

I have a code below and it has strange behavior,Line of code after closing of While Loop is not executing. If i write those lines before While loop they got executed. I have searched a lot on this issue but failed.

```
if ((Convert.ToInt32(newDt.Rows[i]["qty"])) > (Convert.ToInt32(newDt1.Rows[i]["qty"])))
            {
                k_batch = Convert.ToInt32(newDt.Rows[i]["batch_num"]);
                label20.Content = k_batch.ToString();
                var dqty = (from row in Addition_result.AsEnumerable()      //retriving value from DataTable
                            where row.Field<int>("batch_num") == k_batch
                            select row.Field<int>("qty")).FirstOrDefault();

                dqty_y = Convert.ToInt32(dqty);
                label16.Content = dqty_y.ToString();


                    con.Open();

                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT quantity,sold_qty,left_qty FROM batch WHERE id='" + k_batch + "'", con);
                    SqlDataReader batch_qty_details = null;
                    batch_qty_details = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

                    while (batch_qty_details.Read())
                    {
                        label16.Content = dqty_y.ToString();
                        batch_qty = Convert.ToInt32(batch_qty_details["quantity"]);
                        batch_left = Convert.ToInt32(batch_qty_details["left_qty"]);
                        batch_sold = Convert.ToInt32(batch_qty_details["sold_qty"]);
                    }  //code after this is not executing

                label18.Content = batch_left.ToString();
                label19.Content = batch_sold.ToString();
                label21.Content = dqty_y.ToString();
                label22.Content = batch_qty.ToString();
                label16.Content = batch_sold + dqty_y;
                label17.Content = batch_left - dqty_y;

                if (((batch_sold + dqty_y) <= batch_qty) && ((batch_left - dqty_y) >= 0))
                {
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update batch set sold_qty=sold_qty+@soldqty2, left_qty=left_qty-@soldqty2 where id=@id2", con);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@soldqty2", Convert.ToInt32(dqty_y));
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id2", Convert.ToInt32(k_batch));
                    rexe = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please Check you Ordered Quantity !");
                }



                con.Close();

            }
        }
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the while loop, see what it does.

Comment: Maybe `batch_qty_details.Read()` still returns true? which means you have a lot of rows?

Comment: You should factor out all that data access code. And the business logic. This is a mess that mixes data access with UI concerns and domain logic and will be very hard to maintain.

Comment: Are you causing an exception and exiting early? Put a try/catch around the `while` loop.

Comment: For the scope of this question, it seems that most of it is irrelevant, which renders the question way more complicated than it ought be. Try to boil it down to a [mcve].

Comment: I have used try catch block around while loop and it has given me exception that connection was not closed. Although i have written con.close() at end of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually there was issue that connection state was already Open and i was trying to open it again. So then i used try-catch block it told me that connection is already open. Now i have changed my code and here it is.

```
if ((Convert.ToInt32(newDt.Rows[i]["qty"])) > (Convert.ToInt32(newDt1.Rows[i]["qty"])))
            {
                k_batch = Convert.ToInt32(newDt.Rows[i]["batch_num"]);
                label20.Content = k_batch.ToString();
                var dqty = (from row in Addition_result.AsEnumerable()      //retriving value from DataTable
                            where row.Field<int>("batch_num") == k_batch
                            select row.Field<int>("qty")).FirstOrDefault();

                dqty_y = Convert.ToInt32(dqty);
                label16.Content = dqty_y.ToString();

                try
                {
                    //con.Open();

                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT quantity,sold_qty,left_qty FROM batch WHERE id='" + k_batch + "'", con);
                    SqlDataReader batch_qty_details = null;
                    batch_qty_details = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

                    while (batch_qty_details.Read())
                    {
                        label16.Content = dqty_y.ToString();
                        batch_qty = Convert.ToInt32(batch_qty_details["quantity"]);
                        batch_left = Convert.ToInt32(batch_qty_details["left_qty"]);
                        batch_sold = Convert.ToInt32(batch_qty_details["sold_qty"]);
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }
                catch(Exception EX)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(EX.ToString());

                }
                label18.Content = batch_left.ToString();
                label19.Content = batch_sold.ToString();
                label21.Content = dqty_y.ToString();
                label22.Content = batch_qty.ToString();
                label16.Content = batch_sold + dqty_y;
                label17.Content = batch_left - dqty_y;


                if (((batch_sold + dqty_y) <= batch_qty) && ((batch_left - dqty_y) >= 0))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update batch set sold_qty=sold_qty+@soldqty2, left_qty=left_qty-@soldqty2 where id=@id2", con);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@soldqty2", Convert.ToInt32(dqty_y));
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id2", Convert.ToInt32(k_batch));
                    rexe = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                else
                {
                    check_qty = -1;


                }






            }
```